# Set range through multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have 5 identical worksheets (named: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50) and want to copy them in a separate file (Name: csv). First of all, I defined the range (the same for all 5) and the macro should search in all worksheets, if the cell values <> "" and 0.

In addition, I want to copy more values if the condition is met. Unfortunately I do not get the values that I want.

Can anyone spot my mistake?

For interest: The code worked pretty well when there is only one worksheet that has served as a source, so I think I've to change/adjust the range. 
Unfortunately my VBA is still very poor and I can't find the solution

```
Sub Sample()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim resultrange As Range
    Dim row As Range

    Dim sheetsArray As Sheets
    Set sheetsArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("10", "20", "30", "40", "50"))
    Dim target As Range
    Dim sheetObject As Worksheet

    For Each sheetObject In sheetsArray
        Set target = sheetObject.Range("H6:T529")
    Next sheetObject


    Dim cell As Range

    Set resultrange = Sheets("CSV").Range("C2:T1000")


    i = 1
    For Each cell In target
        If (cell.value <> "" And cell.value <> 0) Then
            resultrange.Rows.Cells(i, 5).value = cell.value
            resultrange.Rows.Cells(i, 17).value = Range("A" & cell.row).value
            resultrange.Rows.Cells(i, 18).value = Range(Col_Letter(cell.column) & "2").value
            resultrange.Rows.Cells(i, 2).value = Range(Col_Letter(cell.column) & "1").value

            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cell




End Sub
```

' A function I've copied from an other forum to show the columns in a reasonable way

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to nest your loops. This code...

```
For Each sheetObject In sheetsArray
Set target = sheetObject.Range("H6:T529")
Next sheetObject
```

...does nothing with the `target` range, so when that loop exits you will only be copying the last `Range` that it was set to.

```
Dim cell As Range
Set ResultRange = Sheets("CSV").Range("C2:T1000")
i = 1
For Each sheetObject In sheetsArray
    Set target = sheetObject.Range("H6:T529")
    For Each cell In target
        With target.Worksheet
            If (cell.Value <> "" And cell.Value <> 0) Then
                ResultRange.Rows.Cells(i, 5).Value = cell.Value
                ResultRange.Rows.Cells(i, 17).Value = .Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value
                ResultRange.Rows.Cells(i, 18).Value = .Cells(2, cell.Column).Value
                ResultRange.Rows.Cells(i, 2).Value = .Cells(1, cell.Column).Value
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End With
    Next cell
Next sheetObject
```

Comment: Thank you! The Problem right now is, that I only get the values from "`ResultRange.Rows.Cells(i, 5).Value = cell.Value`" the other one is wrong ("`ResultRange.Rows.Cells(i, 17).Value = Range("A" & cell.Row).Value`") or don't appear (the last two conditions). It worked totally fine when I only had one source and the code looked like this: `ResultRange.Rows.Cells(i, 18).Value = Sheets("Sheetname").Range(Col_Letter(cell.Column) & "2").Value`  for example

Comment: @Sven - See edit - I missed that you were using the global `Range`.  Use the `.Cells` from the `target` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! But I still don't get the right values from the 3 conditions. :(

Comment: For example: if the condition has been met (eg. in the sheet 10 in cell O38, I want to copy into the CSV-Worksheet in D the value from A38 and in S the value of O1 and T the value of O2. But it seems like I get V6 (instead of A38) and a lot of 0s back

Comment: @Sven - It was a transposition error from `Worksheet` addressing to `Range` addressing. When you say "worked pretty well when there is only one worksheet" does that mean that it actually ***worked*** before? Your assignment loop is transposing rows and columns in kind of a bizarre way.

Comment: Yes it actually worked before! the only changes to the present have been that I previously have `Set csvrange = Sheets("10").Range("H6:H529")` and then I continued with `For each Cell In csvrange`. Ya things can go crazy when I'm trying something out with VBA. Believe me, I was more suprised then anyone else that it actually worked ;)

Comment: Your new edit has make it work! Thank you very much Comintern! Can you explain why this one works and the previous one didn't? Im really curious

Comment: @Sven - The numeric row and column indexes are relative to the upper left hand corner of the `Range`.  If the upper left of the `Range` isn't "A1", they will be different from the indexes of `Worksheet.Cells(row, col)`.

Comment: @Sven - Also, see item "2" at [this link](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/140252/36565) for an explanation of why you shouldn't use your `Col_Letter` function.